# Redux useSelector with Typescript: Why is the object of type 'unknown'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I've been reading the documentation on using Redux with Typescript and I think I've got everything right, but my compiler is complaining regardless.

This is the problematic line:

```js
// Widget.tsx

const error = useTypedSelector(state => state.error.widgetError)
//                                      ^
// Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571
```

`useTypedSelector` is a recommended by the docs custom hook, so you won't have to typecast `state` as `RootState` whenever you use a selector.

```js
// store.ts
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

```js
// hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { RootState } from './store'

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

I don't understand what the problem is. My entire state tree is typed, and so is the `state` argument in the callback. Hovering over the object in VS Code confirms this.

[image: Yep. That's the state tree.]

I've tried all sorts of typecasting to get around it, I still get the same error.

```js
const error = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.error.widgetError) // no
const error = useSelector<RootState, string | null>(state => state.error.widgetError) // nup
const error = useTypedSelector(state => (state as RootState).error.widgetError) // nuh-uh
```

The only thing that worked was adding `@ts-ignore`, but that kind of defeats half the purpose of using typescript to begin with.

I'm out of both smart and stupid ideas at this point. Halp please?

Comment: Did you defined the RootState ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue on codesandbox, nor in a new react app with the typescript template. It is most likely caused by (incorrectly?) adding ts to an existing js react app.

Answer (score 0):

If RootState is defined then *const error = useSelector<RootState, ErrorState>((state) => state.error).widgetError;* will do the job

Comment: `RootState` is defined and exported from store.ts, like I said in the question. This selector produces the same error. Moreover, this doesn't let me use redux's shallowEqual on nested objects, which will cause some of my components to rerender every second.